# Select another Grease Pencil object in Draw mode Blender 4.0

Tags: shortcut, grease-pencil, selection-tools, keymap

In Blender 2.9x to Blender 3.x, it was possible to switch from one GP object to another while in Draw mode with the right-click selection (so, drawing with left click/stylus tip, and selecting with right click.) It was extremely convenient when working with several GP objects as it can be necessary in some projects.

In Blender 4.0/4.0.2, this isn't possible anymore, and the only way to switch while staying in draw mode is through the outliner. This is quite inconvenient. I have tried looking for the option to change this, but I can't find it.

The "Lock objects mode" option is deactivated as well. I also naively tried adding a RMB shortcut to select a GP object in the draw mode section of the key-binding, but that doesn't work either.

Does anyone have a solution for it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I would like to suggest adding more relative tags such as `shortcut`, `keymap`, or `selection-tools` because personally, I have never heard of the *right-click selection* that you are describing. I cannot recall any way to switch grease pencil objects while in draw mode for any version of Blender.

Comment: @Obfuscate thank you for your suggestion! I have done that. In the older versions of blender, selection was bound to the right mouse click and editing was assigned to the left click (and newer versions allowed to choose)-- and as it happened it was quite handy for GP since the ability to select by clicking was not bound to the same button as drawing/editing.

Comment: Selection tools are bound to *Edit Mode* and switching objects is bound to *Object Mode*. You would switch modes to use the tools tied to each mode. If you are trying to switch objects in any other mode (*Draw Mode*) then, the only way is to select the object you want to switch to inside the outliner.

Comment: What I really wanted was more information on the *right-click selection* that you are describing. If the tool or function exists then, it should have a proper name given to it. As subsequent versions of Blender are released, the tool may have been renamed or replaced. I have used the 3.x and 2.9 series in the past but cannot recall this function at all. Which Blender version did you find this tool in? You may need to do some more personal investigation to find out where you encountered this feature. Ask yourself, was I really using Blender?

Comment: @Obfuscate I was, yeah, and still am. When initializing Blender, or when going in the keymap section in preferences, you should see that the "select with mouse button" option offers both left and right click as options. Right click comes from the 1.xx versions of blender where this was the default, and has since become an option (rather than default.) Again, I was, am, using blender for work, I know what I'm asking, and the possibility to switch from one GP to the other while in draw mode simply with right clicking was possible before.

Comment: I am only trying to point you in a better direction. If the function exists, then you can easily change the keymap for the function or quite possibly duplicate it into some kind of global function for grease pencil objects. As for how, this is definitely a question for `keymap` experts rather than `grease-pencil` users.

Comment: To be fair, I still think asking for more information is acceptable. Screenshots, Blender version, including relative tags, such as `draw-mode`, and etc. The selection tool you are most likely looking for is the one contained in *Object Mode* because it allows you to switch objects. Personally, I have never customized Blender to such a level as what you have worked with so, this goes over my head.